# Am I using too many constructor arguments?

Tags: c++, constructor, code-cleanup

I am writing an enemy class for a 2D tile-based game and it seems necessary to instantiate all private members of the class. This leads to some design difficulties, as I need to pass in 10+ arguments into the constructor. How should I go about cleaning this up, as it is necessary to initialize these values when the object is created?

Here is the code:

```
class Enemy {
private:
    SDL_Rect pos;
    int health;
    int type;
    int id;
    SDL_Texture* default_texture;
    Animation walking_animation;
    Animation attack_animation;
    std::vector<Item> drop_when_killed;
    double velocity_x;
    double velocity_y;
    double attack_range; // in terms of pixels
    int walking_speed;
    int jump_height;
public:
    explicit Enemy(SDL_Rect pos_, int health_, int type_, int id_, 
        SDL_Texture* default_texture_, Animation walking_animation_, 
        Animation attack_animation_, std::vector<Item> drop_when_killed_, double attack_range_,
        int walking_speed_, int jump_height_);
            : pos(pos_), health(health_), type(type_), id(id_), default_texture(default_texture_),
            walking_animation(walking_animation_), attack_animation(attack_animation_),
            drop_when_killed(drop_when_killed_), attack_range(attack_range_),
            walking_speed(walking_speed_), jump_height(jump_height_) {};
    void WalkToPlayer(SDL_Rect player_pos);
    void AttackPlayer(Character& ch);
    void TakeDamage(int damage_num);
    void Die();
    void Update(Character& ch);
    SDL_Rect GetPos() const;
    ~Enemy();
};
```

Comment: Create sub objects, `Velocity` instead of your 2 double for example.

Comment: You *could* consider collecting the variables in a simple `struct` that is then passed to the ctor instead of individual arguments.. sometimes that's nicer.

Comment: Consider how many things this class does. You have enemy stats, game logic, and rendering logic all in the same class. If any one of these changes, the class and anything dependent on it do as well.

Comment: The question should be: Is this class to large? The answer is yes.

Comment: The thing is, do you want to hard-code those stats? If not, might I suggest that you read in the stats from file instead? Would make the signature something like `explicit Enemy(SDL_Rect pos, const std::string& file)`. You could also think about a class `EnemyType` which stores default values, with the program initially creating a library of those from which the actual `Enemy` instances are created like `explicit Enemy(SDL_Rect pos, const EnemyType& type)`. You could also differentiate between enemy logic and enemy appearance/position as separate classes that compose into the actual class.

Comment: @rustyx Actually, since these are being copied for storage as a member, taking them by value is the right thing to do. Then they are either copied at the callsite (and they need to be), or they are `std::move`d at the callsite (because the programmer decided they could be). Though there should be a `std::move` in the member-initialiser (`drop_when_killed(std::move(drop_when_killed_))`). Your solution of a `const` reference prevents the move case, with no gain for the copy case.

Comment: @Aziuth: Class with only constructor taking file would be harder to test.

Comment: @Jarod42 Think you meant to tag Aziuth? Also you're absolutely right. File reading should be done elsewhere (though a `static` factory member of `Enemy` could be appropriate)

Comment: @Jarod42 No problem